# Blazor - Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-5.0

I designing an in-house app that requires user authenticate against the AD.  With that said, user has to provide his/her id/password at the login screen in order for the authentication.  (*We don't want anyone can just open the app and do whatever*)

I have gone through several articles about setting up the environment and use the existing identity via System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().  No one talks about authenticating via information provided by the UI.

I have the login form built and I have a customized AuthenticationStateProvider, but I don't know how to pass the credential that I got from the user to Windows, so it can authenticate it with AD.

Can someone shed some light that as how I can go about doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: What have you attempted to implement and what hasn't worked?

Comment: @DanielMann  I got the login screen built, but can't figure out what method I can pass the user id and password to in order to get the AD authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the [.NET Standard LDAP client library](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) for that, it works fine.

Use it like this:

```
using (var cn = new LdapConnection())
{
     // connect to AD host
     cn.Connect("your_ad", 389);
     try
     {
         cn.Bind("user@domain", "pwd");
     }
     catch(LdapException e)
     {
        // invalid credentials
     }
}
```

Comment: @Stefan...thank you!  through your lead, I've found the package I need...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Through Stefan's lead, I've found the package System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.  The usage is pretty similar to the Novell mentioned by Stefan.  Below is the test code that I plan to integrate into the AuthenticationStateProvider.

```
using (var cn = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ad_servername")))
{
    try
    {
        // this how you can verify the password of an user
        cn.Bind(new NetworkCredential("myid", "mypwd"));

        
    }
    catch(LdapException l)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logon failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Johnny, I have a similar need, would you be willing to post your code as to how you accomplished this.

Comment: @BarnumBailey...the code is already posted...what else are you looking for?